Is there a way to make mapped type which takes optional or array values only
I have type:
type Primitive = number | string | boolean | object | symbol;
and a function which I want to be sure gets objects which have all properties of type Primitive | undefined or Primitive[] but which can't have properties of type Primitive.
I tried making type OptionalPrimitive = (number | undefined) | (string | undefined) | (boolean | undefined) | (object | undefined) | (symbol | undefined);
and later using it in mapped type:
type SelectorProps = {
    [key: string]: OptionalPrimitive | Primitive[];
    // or [key: string]: (Primitive | undefined) | Primitive[];
}

but it doesn't work as expected.
So I want to make type which is compatible with objects of this type
type T1 = {
    a?: boolean
    b?: Object
    c: string[]
}

But of this type not:
type T2 = {
    a: boolean,
    b?: string[],
}


This isn't making a lot of sense to me. Could you format this as actual code we can copy and paste to be a [mre]? What does "it doesn't work" mean? (Note that for code to be a [mre] we need a good description of the issue, and "it doesn't work" is explicitly called out in that doc as insufficient".) There's no mapped type in this example code; you seem to have an index signature instead.  What does T1, T2 being "ok" mean? Please [edit] to fix these issues.

I've edited question. Goal I want to achieve is to make a type SelectorProps which I can use in my generic function someGenerator<T extends SelectorProps>(props: T). And if I call someGenerator with object of type T1 intellisense to not mark it as error and if I call someGenerator with objects of type T2 I want intellisense to mark it as error.

There’s no specific type that works this way. You could write a generic type to act as a constraint, but then you’d need a helper function to help with inference. I’ll send an example when I get off mobile.

it would be appreciated

• Note that your SelectorProps is not a mapped type. Do you mind if I edit to fix the terminology? • This playground link is the example. SelectorProps<T> is sued to validate T against your requirement. If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

This is exactly what I was looking for, I think I get how it works. Thanks! Feel free to edit whatever you want. @jcalz

There is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way. Since {a: boolean} is assignable to {a?: boolean}, then if {a?: boolean} is meant to be assignable to SelectorProps, then {a: boolean} will also.
Instead, you'd need to write a generic type, SelectorProps<T>, that acts as a constraint on T. It's more like a validation than a type. If T extends SelectorProps<T>, then it's valid; otherwise, it's invalid.
Here's one possible approach:
type SelectorProps<T extends object> =
  { [K in keyof T]: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? Primitive : Primitive[] }

The conditional type check, {} extends Pick<T, K> is checking whether or not K is optional in T. The insight is that {} extends {a?: any} but not {a: any}.  And Pick<T, K> just looks at the part of T with the property K. So if {} extends Pick<T, K> then K is optional, otherwise not.

That type works, but by itself it's really annoying to use directly because you'd have to write out your type twice, like
type T1 = {
  a?: boolean
  b?: object
  c: string[]
}
declare const t1: T1;
const sp1: SelectorProps<T1> = t1; // okay

type T2 = {
  a: boolean,
  b?: string[],
}
declare const t2: T2;
const sp2: SelectorProps<T2> = t2; // error!

It would be nice if you could just write SelectorProps or SelectorProps<infer> and have TS infer the type argument instead of writing types twice, but this is a missing feature of TypeScript at requested at microsoft/TypeScript#32794. Until and unless that's implemented we need another approach.

TypeScript won't infer generic type arguments in generic types, but it will do so when you call generic functions. So we can write a generic helper function that just returns its input, and serves to infer the type argument:
const selectorProps = <T extends SelectorProps<T>>(t: T) => t;

declare const t1: T1;
const sp1 = selectorProps(t1); // okay

declare const t2: T2;
const sp2 = selectorProps(t2); // error!
/* Argument of type 'T2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SelectorProps<T2>'.
  Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Primitive[]'.(2345) */

Now it works as desired, where you get errors telling you what's wrong with your type if it doesn't match your intended constraint. If you squint, you could see const sp1 = selectorProps(t1) as similar to const sp1: SelectorProps = t1, except the function call version actually works.
Playground link to code
